# django-configurations can't find my configuration when using uwsgi

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I'm trying to migrate a `Django==2.1` project from one AWS instance to another. I did not create the project so I'm not sure exactly all the steps that they followed for deployment. I see that `uWSGI==2.0.19.1` is in the requirements.txt file, so I'm trying to use that to run the project at port 8000.

The project also uses the library `django-configurations==2.1` to manage multiple configurations. They are in a folder called `config` with this structure.

```
project/
  config/
    __init__.py
    common.py
    development.py
    local.py
    production.py
    staging.py
  manage.py
  wsgi.py
  ...
```

The `__init__.py` file inside the config folder contains the following:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from .local import Local
from .staging import Staging
from .production import Production
from .development import Development
```

I'm trying to run the following command:
`uwsgi --http :8000 --module wsgi:application --chdir=/path/to/project`
And I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configurations/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configurations/importer.py", line 163, in load_module
    mod.__package__))
  File "/path/to/project/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configurations/importer.py", line 159, in load_module
    cls = getattr(mod, self.name)
AttributeError: Couldn't find configuration 'Production
' in module 'config':  module 'config' has no attribute 'Production
' 
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 20490, cores: 1)
```

So it seems like an issue with django-configurations, but it works fine if I just run the server with `DJANGO_CONFIGURATION=Production manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

If I try to run the same line of code that throws the error in the django shell, it works:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import config
>>> getattr(config, 'Production')
<Configuration 'config.production.Production'>
```

The `wsgi.py` file contains this:

```
import os
if os.getenv('local_settings'):
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "local.settings")
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
else:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION", "Production")
    from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

I appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 0):

Your uwsgi configuration is a bit confusing

```
[uwsgi]
basedir = %d
chdir = %(basedir)

master=True
vacuum=True

max-requests=5000
pythonpath = %(basedir)src/
wsgi-file  = %(basedir)src/bear/wsgi.py
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=bear.settings.production

; -- Static serve
mimefile   = %(basedir)uwsgi.mime
static-gzip-all = true
static-check = %(basedir)public
static-safe = %(basedir)public
```

Create a uwsgi.ini file where you define the:

- pythonpath= Defines the main directory of the project.
- wsgi-file=locate the django uwsgi.py file
- env=uwsgi will run in production mode. Define the environment
- static-check=Locate the static file manager or you can serve it with nginx you can choose **collectstatic**
- mimefile=[mimefile.mime](https://gist.github.com/josuedjh3/0e13d41316a37d033b9a52e1b9260338)

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --http :8000
```

example: https://github.com/LabTrendig/django-bear